# Incorrect error message when using an attempted tag synonym or plural thereof

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms, plurals

On Travel.SE, there's a tag "nepali-citizens", which currently has an attempted synonym "nepalese-citizen".

If I try using "nepalese-citizen" or "nepalese-citizens" as tags, confusing error messages occur

[image]

> You are attempting to create the tag [nepalese-citizens]; however the tag [nepalese-citizens] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta

[image]

> You are attempting to create the tag [nepalese-citizens]; however the tag [nepalese-citizens] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta

I searched for similar bugs, but the most recent were marked as resolved and were from 2014.

Comment: I think this was implemented as a blacklist entry, not a synonym. If it were a synonym, it would automatically replace it and wouldn't even show you an error message. Blacklist entries show a custom message just like the one you mentioned. The actual error here is that the custom error message for this specific blacklist entry has a typo.

Comment: At the very least, the typo should be fixed. A better fix would be to remove the blacklist entry and replace it with a synonym.